# $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors in HH R

Tags: r, rscript

I am trying to generate this graph. 
[Using this package](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=HH%3aae.dotplot)

Following is in datafile
         RAND,PREF,SEA,SN

```
Cummulative,Q1,68,1238
Current,Q1,67,1243
Cummulative,Q2,70,1238
Current,Q2,69,1243
Cummulative,Q3,75,1238
Current,Q3,75,1243
Cummulative,Q4,78,1238
Current,Q4,81,1243
Cummulative,Q5,71,1238
Current,Q5,68,1243
Cummulative,Q6,77,1238
Current,Q6,76,1243
Cummulative,Q7,78,1238
Current,Q7,80,1243
Cummulative,Q8,78,1238
Current,Q8,81,1243
Cummulative,Q9,69,1238
Current,Q9,68,1243
Cummulative,Q10,69,1238
Current,Q10,68,1243
Cummulative,Q11,73,1238
Current,Q11,74,1243
Cummulative,Q12,77,1238
Current,Q12,79,1243
Cummulative,Q13,74,1238
Current,Q13,73,1243
Cummulative,Q14,76,1238
Current,Q14,75,1243
Cummulative,Q15,71,1238
Current,Q15,72,1243
Cummulative,Q16,63,1238
Current,Q16,67,1243
Cummulative,Q17,71,1238
Current,Q17,70,1243
```

code:

```
eqdata <- read.table(datafile , header = T,sep=",")
#eqdata <- as.data.frame(eqdata)
eqdata1 <- hh(eqdata)

aed <- logrelrisk(eqdata1)

p <- ae.dotplot(aed, A.name="TREATMENT A (N=216)",B.name="TREATMENT B (N=431)")
```

Output:
Error in ae$SAE : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Calls: logrelrisk

any help much appreciated.

Comment: Its working now!!!

Problem was SEA. Its infact SAE. came to know when i saw function definition. 
All good now.

Comment: Did you also have to remove `eqdata1 <- hh(eqdata)` as suggested below? If so, it would be important to indicate this (for example by accepting the answer) so that others with a similar problem who find this post know all they need to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cut out the `eqdata1 <- hh(eqdata)` line. From the `?hh` documentation, this function merely returns the path to the specified file, and is thus not a `data.frame`, as is required by `logrelrisk()`.

```
eqdata <- read.table(datafile , header = T,sep=",")
#eqdata <- as.data.frame(eqdata)
# eqdata1 <- hh(eqdata)

aed <- logrelrisk(eqdata)

p <- ae.dotplot(aed, A.name="TREATMENT A (N=216)",B.name="TREATMENT B (N=431)")
```

Comment: then it gives following error
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PCT", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 34
Calls: logrelrisk -> $<- -> $<-.data.frame

I m really stuck please help :(

Comment: Ahhh... Now I see that one of your column names is incorrect. `SEA` should be `SAE`. Does that do it? (the `hh` line should still be taken out)